# Redirection with .htaccess, hiding the original URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a domain, www.mydomain2.com, that I'd like being redirected to www.mydomain1.com/folder_site2/ but I'd like the URL that appears in the address bar being "www.mydomaine2.com" instead of the "www.mydomain1.com/folder_site2/"

After searches in the Apache documentation, I made my .htaccess looking like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder_site2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder_site2/$1 [L]
```

I first thought it was working fine, as, when I typed "mydomain2.com", I was correctly redirected on "www.mydomain1.com/folder_site2/" with "mydomain2.com" as visible URL.
But it seems it's impossible to reach a sub-folder. Any URL like "mydomain2.com/subfolder/text.html" would reach to a 404 (while it was possible to reach via "mydomain1.com/folder_site2/subfolder/text.html")

What have I done wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are both mydomain1 and mydomain2 pointing to the same server and root directory?

Comment: They point on the same server, and I might sound silly, but I was only able to configure the DNS, so I couldn't specify a root directory for mydomain2 (neither for mydomain1, actually), that's why I'm trying to use .htaccess.